# How to calculate number of occurrence of a character at beginning in a List of String using Scala

Tags: scala

I am new to Scala and I want to calculate number of occurrences of a character in which start with a particular alphabet in a list of Strings.

For example-

```
val test1 : List[String] = List("zero","zebra","zenith","tiger","mosquito")
```

I have defined above List of Strings and I want to calculate count of all strings which start with "z".
I tried with below code-

```
scala> test2.count(s=> s.charAt(0) == "z")
res7: Int = 0
```

It is giving me result as 0. I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Please suggest.

Comment: `s.charAt(0)` is `Char`, and `"z"` is `String`. `'z' == "z"` is `false`.

Comment: http://www.wartremover.org/doc/warts.html#equals

Answer (score 2):

Character values are delimited by single quotes. Double quotes are reserved for strings:

```
val test : List[String] = List("zero","zebra","zenith","tiger","mosquito")
test.count(_.charAt(0) == 'z') // 3: Int
```

Answer (score 0):

you can simply use `filter` and find the `length` of the `list`

```
println(test1.filter(_.startsWith("z")).length)
```

If you want to ignore the cases (uppercase or lowercase) you can add .toLowerCase as

```
println(test1.filter(_.toLowerCase.startsWith("z")).length)
```

I hope the answer is helpful